Cement on interior hallway walls with thin wallboard
This is a small home built in 1914.  The house has plaster walls with wood lath.  In the hallway there was wainscot paneling. When I removed the paneling some was glued to the wall and the wallboard came off in places with the glue and exposed cement.  At first I thought it was because of where the old chimney is, but when I did the other hallway walls I found cement under them too.
Why did they cement the walls in the interior hallway?  There is like quarter inch drywall on top of it.  Can I just drywall patch these spots over the cement?  It is dry and there is no sign it ever was wet.  Just in case this could have something to do with the reason, there is a water bin in the attic that looks like a cow waterer, I was told that’s what they used before running water as it was gravity fed water.

You know now that I look at it, I said quarter inch so it’s actually more like eighth inch.  It was painted so now that you ask I believe it may be thin plaster over the cement.  Took a pic but can’t get it to load here

Since I couldn’t get the picture to load I took my chances.  Thanks Isherwood for reminding me it’s plaster not drywall, it was too thin to be drywall.  I plastered over the cement.  After it was dry I skim coated with drywall mud.  I will prime next.  It’s looking good and plaster at the cement is better than drywall mud.  I’d still love to know why there is cement behind this plaster but luckily I didn’t damage the cement just some of the plaster.
